# C# не выводит все символы которые нужно использовать

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Использую прежнюю версию консоли, кодировка `CP866`, символов стало больше. Работаю в программе Visual Studio 2017. По  какой-то причине не хочет выводит все символы как на этом рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод в консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выводе на консоль, заметны знаки `?` вместо символов таблицы с кодировкой `CP866`. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, заранее спасибо!

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `кодировка 866, символов стало больше` - это как? где их стало больше?

Comment: Когда я использовал новую версию консоли, знаков ? было больше. При переходе на старую версию, знаков ? стало меньше. Я не знаю как это объяснить, извините.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопался я на одном форуме и нашел прекрасный ответ.

По причине того, что я не хочу попросту копировать ответ, даю ссылку, где подробно объяснено, как рекомендуется пользоваться кодировками. Ответ очень исчерпывающий и полезный. [Ссылка](https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=268911) (см. сообщение #13)

Кратко: преобразование (char)i и обратное - не всегда корректное с точки зрения кодировки. Поэтому для данного случая необходимо сначала создать массив байтов, где будет содержаться `{0, 1, 2, ..., 254, 255}` и декодировать его в соответствии с целевой кодировкой.

В итоге код будет таким:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var recievedBytes = new byte[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < recievedBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        recievedBytes[i] = (byte)i;
    }

    var str = Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(recievedBytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(str[i] + " ");
        if (i % 16 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Результат работы программы:

[image: Результат]

Comment: У меня данный код выводит множество знаков вопросов. Возможно, дело в локали ОС, отличной от русской, возможно, дело в шрифте консоли. Но факт, что все равно не всегда этот код поможет.

Comment: Шрифт тут точно ни при чем, потому что у меня на разных шрифтах работает. Скорее всего, локаль.

Comment: Попробуйте установить Culture на русский

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка консоли установлена ​​в ASCII или не совместимую с вашим выводом кодировку.
Попробуйте изменить кодировку перед отправкой вывода:

```
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.<ваша кодировка>;
```

В вашем случае, вот эта команда переведет консоль в режим кодовой страницы 866:

```
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
```

Варианты кодировок которые поддерживает ваша консоль с текущими настройками можно посмотреть командой `chcp` выполненной из командной строки.

Описание на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_OutputEncoding)

Если использовать Unicode, то консоль должна использовать шрифт TrueType, такие как Lucida Console или Consolas, для отображения символов. По умолчанию консоль отображает UTF-16, в современных системах.

В Windows 10 необходимо проверить настройки региона и языка и установить поддержку для требуемого языка.

И более корректный пример для теста консоли например в кодировке UTF-8:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static class ConsoleOutputTest {
    public static void Main() {
        string old = Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage.ToString();
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine(old + " : " + Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage.ToString());
        for (var i = 0; i <= 256; i++) {
            Console.Write(Strings.ChrW(i));
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не поможет. Большинство символов все равно останутся "вопросиками".

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, Аргументируйте если не сложно.

Comment: Я просто это попробовал у себя на машине. (p.s. в первой редакции ответа). В новой редакции ответ не проверял

Comment: Первой редакции ответа не было :) был процесс его написания